# Inserting a big array of object in mongodb from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bigdata

I need to insert a big array of objects (about 1.5-2 millions) in mongodb from nodejs. How can i improve my inserting?

This is my code:

```
var sizeOfArray = arrayOfObjects.length; //sizeOfArray about 1.5-2 millions
for(var i = 0; i < sizeOfResult; ++i) {
  newKey = {
    field_1: result[i][1],
    field_2: result[i][2],
    field_3: result[i][3]
  };
  collection.insert(newKey, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      log.error('Error insert: ' + err);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [bulk](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_4_and_2_6.html#ordered-unordered-bulk-operations) inserts.

There are two types of bulk operations:

> 1. Ordered bulk operations. These operations execute all the operation in order and error out on the first write error.
> 2. Unordered bulk operations. These operations execute all the operations in parallel and aggregates up all the errors. Unordered
>      bulk operations do not guarantee order of execution.

So you can do something like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://myserver:27017/test", function(err, db) {
    // Get the collection
    var col = db.collection('myColl');

    // Initialize the Ordered Batch
    // You can use initializeUnorderedBulkOp to initialize Unordered Batch
    var batch = col.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

    for (var i = 0; i < sizeOfResult; ++i) {
      var newKey = {
          field_1: result[i][1],
          field_2: result[i][2],
          field_3: result[i][3]
      };
      batch.insert(newKey);
    }

    // Execute the operations
    batch.execute(function(err, result) {
      console.dir(err);
      console.dir(result);
      db.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: @user3386802 I added some code to get the collection by using native MongoDB node.js driver.

Comment: Also it will be good to manage memory efficiency through data streaming to handle large chunks of data.

Answer (score 1):

As For Version > 3.2, **insertMany** has been introduced which uses *bulkWrite* under the hood for bulk insert purposes only.

- insertMany supports *ordered* and *unordered* inserts. **Unordered** being faster as mongo decides the ordering. Likewise your implementation for best through-put should be ::

  ```
     var sizeOfArray = arrayOfObjects.length;
     for(var i = 0; i < sizeOfResult; ++i) {
       newKey = {
        field_1: result[i][1],
        field_2: result[i][2],
        field_3: result[i][3]
       };
     }
     collection.insertMany(newKey, { ordered: false }).then((res) => {
     console.log("Number of records inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
     })
  ```