# Insert 500k records in mongodb one by one causes heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to insert 500 000 records records in mongodb 
collection. These values are stored in csv and parsed, and then stored to an array. And using recursive functions inserting records one by one and when one record is inserted again the same function is called.
This process works for 200 000 records but when records size is increased more than 200 000 it causes heap out of memory (JS stack trace).

Below is the recursive function i am using

```
function insertMongoSingle(fileRows, x, total){
    if(x < total){
        let item = fileRows.shift();
        let record  = new Record({i:item}, false);
        record.save(function(error, contact){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                x++;
                insertMongoSingle(fileRows, x ,total);
            }else{
                x++;
                insertMongoSingle(fileRows, x, total);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        console.log('completed');
    }
}
```

where x is the count, fileRows is the total records in array of objects and total is length of fileRows

Comment: is total just fileRows.length? and can you show the function that produces fileRows, this is very inefficient to have 500,000 items in 1 array & there will be a better way.

Comment: Can't you read the data in chunks and process?

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest going with [bulk insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/)  mongo capabilities.

A detailed answer was already given on stackoverflow: [Inserting a big array of object in mongodb from nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928267/inserting-a-big-array-of-object-in-mongodb-from-nodejs)

Or if you want an alternate solution you can check my loading example:
[Loading 10K of seed data](https://www.alxolr.com/articles/squeeze-node-js-performance-with-flame-graphs#seed-data)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the choice to import CSV data using the command line? if you have that could be a better option using `mongoimport`. If not so and want to parse and customize data before saving to DB then go with CSV stream parser. Collect and process records in batches. Let's say each batch has 5000 records, Insert each batch with  `Model.insertMany(records), flush it and create a new batch, process and repeat until you finish all batches(records).

**mongoimport**

```
 mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionName --type csv --file input.csv --headerline
```

**Programmatically:**

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const fs =   require('fs')
let records = [];
let limits = 5000
fs.createReadStream('my.csv')
    .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true}))
    .on('error', error => console.error(error))
    .on('data', row => {
         // customize your data here 
        records.push(row);
       if(recors.legth==limits) {
       Model.insertMany(records)
       records = [];
      }
     })
    .on('end', rowCount => {
   });
```