# Timeout while adding collection to mongodb mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, directory

I'm trying to read specific files contained in a directory. Although the directory might contain multiple nested directories and that's why I've used this recursive function.

```
var express = require('express');
var nodegit = require('nodegit');
var path = require('path');
var fse = require("fs-extra");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

require('dotenv/config');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test').
  catch(error => console.log(error));

app.get("/", ());
...
...

var collection = [];
const readAllFolder = (pathToRepo) => {
  const readDirMain = fse.readdirSync(pathToRepo);

  readDirMain.forEach((file) => {
    if (file == "i.json") {
      var rawdata = fse.readFileSync(pathToRepo + "/" + file);
      var data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
      for (i in data['l']) {
        data[data['l'][i]['name']] = data['l'][i]['url']
      }
      delete data['l'];
      if (fse.existsSync(pathToRepo + "/l.png")) {
        data['img'] = {
          data: fse.readFileSync(pathToRepo + "/l.png"),
          contentType: 'image/png'
        }
      }
      var my_data = new model(data);
      if(condition) collection.push(my_data);
      //my_data.save();
    } else {
      if (fse.lstatSync(pathToRepo + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
        readAllFolder(pathToRepo + "/" + file);
      }
    }
  });
};

app.listen(process.env.PORT_SERVER, () => console.log(`Live at: http://localhost:${process.env.PORT_SERVER}`));
```

The problem is that I get an error when the code finishes going through each file:

```
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797:32)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10
    at /Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1167:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:340:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../app.js:19:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:149
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation "models.insertOne()" buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:149:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

I've also tried to use the insertMany function, in order to avoid multiple calls, but still didn't work. Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: How do you connect to the db?

Comment: @AlexBlex I've updated my question. I've just put the most important part.

Comment: Could you confirm you actually connected to the db? e.g. with `mongoose.connection.once("open", () => console.log("connected to the db")` right after `mongoose.connect` . Just to confirm  it's not the case described in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering The error message might be misleading.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes it always connects. I can do basic save, if there are not too many operations. Although once I go through each file, I get this error

Comment: Fair enough. Try to disable buffering for the model with `bufferCommands: false,` option or make readAllFolder  async and do `await my_data.save();`  - it will dramatically slow it down as you will write 1 file at a time but it will guarantee you don't build up a massive queue of  pending promises.  I it works you can optimise it later with batch operations and running several writes in parallel (no more than number of open connections in the pool)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `await` didn't work, but `bufferCommands` did. If I wanted instead to put everything in a single array to then use insertMany, hence speeding up the whole process, how shall I do it? I can't seem to get back the whole collection

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, just inserting `await` won't help - you need to update upstream functions to respect it. The forEach loop in particular, so a bit of refactoring up to  readAllFolder to make it async.

Comment: Yes I've tried with refactoring the whole function, plus also the forEach loop. But that didn't suffice. Now I'm trying to put everything in an array, but my collection is always blank. Any idea?

Comment: Mongoose doesn't have anything special for bulk writes, so you will need to use bare mongodb queries, e.g. insertMany https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents and bulk inserts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928267/inserting-a-big-array-of-object-in-mongodb-from-nodejs

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've updated my question, because I thought I left the part of bulk queries. In the code now you can see that I'm trying to push (under certain condition) data into the array. Unfortunately it is always empty, do you know why? Thanks for the help

Comment: add some console.debug before collection.push to confirm the condition evaluated to true at least one. It's pure JS debugging, not related to mongo nor mongoose

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that